# Is it possible to extend a generic class while restricting the generic type?

Tags: java, generics

Suppose I have abstract classes (or, indeed, interfaces)

```
public abstract class Animal

public abstract class Bird Extends Animal
```

and a generic class

```
public class Lifestyle<A extends Animal>
```

So we might create a `Lifestyle<Lion>` object.

The `Lifestyle` class contains methods that animals can use to tell them how to walk around, find food, interact with other animals of the same species, etc.  Now suppose I want to extend this class to a special `BirdLifestyle` class that tells `Bird`s how to do all the above things, but also tells them how to `fly` and use all of the extra methods in the `Bird` class.  I want to be able to create a `BirdLifestyle<Eagle>` object, for instance.  I'm pretty sure that the following won't compile:

```
public class BirdLifestyle<B extends Bird> extends Lifestyle<A extends Animal>
```

and the only alternative I can think of is rather nasty:

```
public class BirdLifestyle<B extends Bird>
{
  private Lifestyle<B> lifestyle // tells the bird how to do animal things.

  public Lifestyle<B> getLifestyle()
  {
    return lifestyle;
  }

  // Bird-specific methods.
}
```

We could then get all of the methods from `Animal` by calling `getLifestyle().walk()` or things like that.

Now suppose that my friends have all created their own implementations of these four classes and that we want to link them using interfaces.  So we create

```
public interface LifestyleInterface
{
  public void walk();

  // etc.
}

public interface AvianLifestyleInterface extends LifestyleInterface
{
  public void fly();

  // etc.
}
```

My friends are all more specialize, so they've all written things like:

```
public class LionLifestyle implements LifestyleInterface
```

or

```
public class EagleLifestyle implements AvianLifestyleInterface
```

while I can write:

```
public class Lifestyle<A extends Animal> implements LifestyleInterface
```

But I *can't* now write:

```
public class BirdLifestyle<B extends Bird> implements AvianLifestyleInterface
```

even if my `BirdLifestyle` class overrides all the methods introduced in `AvianLifestyleInterface`.  This is because `BirdLifestyle` is not a superclass of `Lifestyle`.  The only way round this is to create lots of entry-point methods such as:

```
public class BirdLifestyle<B extends Bird>
{
  private Lifestyle<B> lifestyle;

  public Lifestyle<B> getLifestyle()
  {
    return lifestyle;
  }

  // 'AvianLifestyleInterface' methods.

  @Override
  public void fly()
  {
    // Code for flying.
  }

  // etc.

  // 'LifestyleInterface' methods.

  @Override
  public void walk()
  {
    getLifestyle().walk();
  }

  // etc., creating a similar one-line method for each method in 
  // 'LifestyleInterface' that is just an entry-point to the same 
  // method in the 'Lifestyle<A>' object.
}
```

This seems like an unnecessary amount of code to write, and a lot of the code is written in a fairly mechanical way, which breaks several programming rules.  For example, if I want to add any methods to the `LifestyleInterface` interface then I need to remember to add a new one-line method into the `BirdLifestyle` class.  Is there a cleaner way?

Comment: I think this will work: `public class BirdLifestyle<B extends Bird> extends Lifestyle<B>`.

Comment: You've mixed up too many things in your question, and it is making it hard to understand. Moreover, you don't tell what error you get wherever you're saying it doesn't work. What issues you faced while making `BirdLifestyle` implement the `AvianLifestyleInterface` interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a little unclear to me what you are really asking here, but it seems that your first attempt can be easily remedied by:

```
public class BirdLifestyle<B extends Bird> extends Lifestyle<B> {
    // ...
}
```

`Lifestyle` is already declared to be generic as `Lifestyle<A extends Animal>`, no need to repeat what the generic type bound is (and as you say, it won't compile).

Similarly:

```
public class BirdLifestyle<B extends Bird> extends Lifestyle<B> implements AvianLifestyleInterface {
   // ...
}
```

Will work.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't realize you could do that, but it makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty much lost in your question right now. But you can surely change your `BirdLifestyle` class to:

```
public class BirdLifestyle extends Lifestyle<Bird> { }
```

Don't see why you would make `BirdLifestyle` itself a generic class here. Will update the answer if I understand other part of the question.

If you're moving to interfaces, then you can just do:

```
public class BirdLifestyle implements AvianLifestyleInterface { }
```

Again, why would you make the class generic? The name `BirdLifeStyle` should really describe the life style of a bird. Do you have different kinds of `Bird`?

Comment: Thanks very much.  Sorry, yes - there are different kinds of `Bird`; I'll try and update the question to make that clearer.